# Render rails view with javascript effects like fadein, slides etc

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want some static pages to be rendered to the client with some slide effect or maybe a fadein.
How do you apply this to views before they are rendered? Its very easy to do a fadeout when the pages content has been loaded. But how do you do a fadein?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right; don't use JavaScript to make the elements invisible on initial load; that JavaScript will load too late, and you'll get some horrible flashing.

Instead, when you initially serve the page, render it so that it gives the outermost divs that you want to hide (or be transparent, or whatever) a class that, when combined with your CSS, will make the elements not display, or invisible, or whatever.  *Then*, use JavaScript to fade those elements *in.*